# yii bootstrap sort default order by ASC or DESC

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, sorting, yii

Hye i have two options where one is to sort according to the title and the other is by created.
When i implement sortable attributes in my function both of this option have a default sort  of ascending order. I want my title in default ascending but my latest is in descending. Below is my code:

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbListView',array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_view',
    //'template' => '{items} {pager}',
    'ajaxUpdate' => false,
    'sortableAttributes'=>array(
        'title' => '<span class="label label-warning">Title</span>',
        'created'=>'<span class="label label-warning">Latest</span>',

    ),
)); ?>
```

I have read in the yii **[forum](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/18439-clistview-sortableattributes-how-to-set-default-order/)** where i need to implement this in my data provider.

`$dataProvider->sort->defaultOrder='dateCreate ASC';`

After implement that code as below:

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbListView',array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider->sort->defaultOrder='created DESC',
    'itemView'=>'_view',
    //'template' => '{items} {pager}',
    'ajaxUpdate' => false,
    'sortableAttributes'=>array(
        'title' => '<span class="label label-warning">Title</span>',
        'created'=>'<span class="label label-warning">Latest</span>',

    ),
)); ?>
```

Now im getting an error message saying that:

#### Fatal error: Call to a member function getData() on a non-object in /home/smartmob/public_html/framework/zii/widgets/CBaseListView.php on line 111

Can someone help me what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

The following code is invalid. You are setting the gridView's dataprovider to `defaultOrder` instead of `$dataProvider`.

```
'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider->sort->defaultOrder='created DESC',
```

You have to set the `defaultOrder` BEFORE you pass it into the grid i.e

```
$dataProvider->sort->defaultOrder='created DESC';

<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbListView',array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ...
```